# how to remove files that could be with lower/upper case

Tags: linux, bash, files, regular-expression, rm

how to remove files that could be with **lower/upper** case

for example, the file_name could be:

- STOCK.Repo or
- Stock.REPO or
- stOCK.repo or
- stock.repo
- ... etc

I would run:

```
 rm -f $file_name
```

***the goal is to remove file as stock.repo that could be in lower/upper case on remote machine***

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Bash-specific solution:

```
$ shopt -s nocaseglob
```

and then run the `rm` command.

Note to unset this option, use `shopt -u nocaseglob`

For completeness, I would point out an alternative but less elegant solution:

```
$ rm [sS][tT][oO][cC][kK].[rR][eE][pP][oO]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do it using `find` command

`find /path/to/directory -type f -iname stock\.repo -exec rm -f {} \;`

But be very careful. It is working recursively from /path/to/directory.
You should consider using maxdepth option, and getting more familiar with this command before running it on production system where permanent damage can be made.

Comment: Most `find` implementations also has `-delete`. For safety, if using `-exec rm`, you could instead use `-ok rm`.

Comment: `find` knows `-delete`

Comment: Also, there is no need to escape the dot in the name pattern.

Answer (score 0):

With the `zsh` and `ksh93` shells, you can turn case-insensitive matching on a per-glob basis:

- `zsh`:

  ```
  set -o extendedglob # best in ~/.zshrc
  rm -- (#i)$filename
  ```
- `ksh93`:

  ```
  rm -- ~(i:"$filename")
  ```

  Note however, that if there's no matching file a literal `~(i:stock.repo)` would be passed to `rm`. And if that file exists, it would be removed (`zsh` above would fail with an error and not call `rm` at all in that case).

  You could however set the `N` flag in addition to the `i` flag:

  ```
  rm -- ~(Ni:"$filename")
  ```

  Then, in case of no-match, `rm` would be called, but with an empty argument (probably a bug caused by the quotes as it's meant to pass *no* argument at all then). You'd then get a `rm: cannot remove '': No such file or directory` kind of error but at least it wouldn't remove the wrong file.

Answer (score -1):

I have done by using below method. Answer provided above is quite good. Below one is my try

```
ls -ltr | awk '{print $9}' | sed -n '/^STOCK.Repo$/Ip'  |awk '{print "rm" " " $1}'| sh
```

Comment: It's bad practice to parse `ls`, also you rely on the filenames returned from `ls` to have no spaces. This would remove not only `STOCK.Repo` but also `STOCK.Repo1` etc. Furthermore, if a file is called `STOCK.Repo;reboot` this may reboot the machine.

Comment: Yes i accept parsing ls output is bad pratice and i edited the answer so it will delete only the file STOCK.Repo

Comment: Given the Linux tag, you could use gawk's ENDFILE functionality to avoid ls, an awk call, sed, *and* the pipe to sh with: `gawk 'ENDFILE { IGNORECASE=1; if (FILENAME ~ /^stock\.repo$/) system("rm " FILENAME); }' *` -- although I'd be cautious about removing files this way unless you knew (as we do here) exactly what the filenames are.